# Delphi XE6 - SOAP built with 'USE_INDY' connecting to a webservice over a proxy issue

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, proxy, delphi-xe6

I have an application which connects to a webservice using [THttpRio](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SOAPHTTPClient_THTTPRIO.html) component. Webservice has basic authentication. I've compiled the Delphi SOAP units using the 'USE_INDY' directive in order that the THttpRio component to use WinHttp.

Now I need to get through a proxy to my webservice. Looking into the Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans unit I've fixed some bugs, but I do not know how I should set up the THttpRio component to get through the proxy.

I've tried to set the proxy property of the HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.Proxy to a string like:

```
http://user:pass@ip:port
```

but I get a `407 Unauthorized` error....

[image]

Proxy application is CCProxy.

Comment: "I've compiled the Delphi SOAP units using the 'USE_INDY' directive in order that the THttpRio component to use WinHttp." - um, **enabling** the `USE_INDY` conditional **does not** enable use of WinHttp, it enables use of Indy! Indy does not use WinHttp. You have to **disable** `USE_INDY` if you want SOAP to use WinHttp.

Comment: To connect `TIdHTTP` to a proxy, the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property (which as `ProxyServer`, `ProxyPort`, `ProxyUsername` and `ProxyPassword` sub-properties) needs to be configured if connecting to an HTTP proxy, or a `TIdSocksInfo` component needs to be attached to `TIdHTTP` if connecting to a SOCKS proxy. I have no idea if Delphi SOAP supports either configuration or not, or how it handles `THttpRIO.HTTPWebNode` when `USE_INDY` is enabled.

Comment: I just checked in XE2, and `THttpRIO` does configure `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` if the `THttpRIO.HTTPWebNode.Proxy` property is in either `http://host[:port]` or `host[:####]` format. However, when a proxy is used, the `HTTPWebNode.UserName` and `HTTPWebNode.Password` are being using for proxy authentication and not for webservice authentication, which is technically wrong as the two authentications need to be handled separately, but `THttpRIO` does not provide a way to set different proxy authentication and webservice authentication credentials.

Comment: Also, if you provide `user:pass` values in either the proxy URL or the webservice URL, `THttpProxy` will simply ignore them. It does let Indy parse the URLs, so it will parse the `user:pass` values, but `THttpRIO` simply ignores any username/password that are extracted, relying on its own `Username` and `Password` properties instead.

Comment: Thank you Remy. But I've fixed how username and password are set in HttpTrans unit(which is bogus). I will try in another way(probably building the app from zero with Indy)

Comment: And fixes you make to the SOAP code should be submitted to Embarcadero.