# How can I force TLS 1.2 when making a SOAP call using THTTPRIO?

Tags: delphi, soap

I imported a WSDL in Delphi 10.4 Update 2 and I have been able to use it successfully until now, when the customer disabled all protocols except TLS 1.2.

How can I force `THTTPRIO` to use TLS 1.2?

Comment: Protocol negotiation should work as long as TLS 1.2 is enabled. Post a small example of trying a connection to this customer that fails ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [THTTPRio TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567820/thttprio-tls-1-2)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was the computer where the application was running on.

Probably because it's a windows server 2008?
Changing to windows server 2016 made the program work again.

thanks!